# use Teapot instead of CubeObject in object recognition

Tags: vuforia

I'm trying to use Teapot instead of the cube object in the object recognition sample app, but the Teapot is placed too far away from my target.

I will really appreciate any help.

Here is my ObjectTargetRenderer:

```
public class ObjectTargetRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SampleAppRendererControl
{
    private static final String LOGTAG = "ObjectTargetRenderer";

    private SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession;
    private ObjectTargets mActivity;
    private SampleAppRenderer mSampleAppRenderer;

    private Vector<Texture> mTextures;
    private int shaderProgramID;
    private int vertexHandle;
    private int textureCoordHandle;
    private int texSampler2DHandle;
    private int mvpMatrixHandle;
    private int opacityHandle;
    private int colorHandle;

    private CubeObject mCubeObject;
    private Teapot mTeapot;

    private Renderer mRenderer;

    private boolean mIsActive = false;


    public ObjectTargetRenderer(ObjectTargets activity,
        SampleApplicationSession session)
    {
        mActivity = activity;
        vuforiaAppSession = session;

        // SampleAppRenderer used to encapsulate the use of RenderingPrimitives setting
        // the device mode AR/VR and stereo mode
        mSampleAppRenderer = new SampleAppRenderer(this, mActivity, Device.MODE.MODE_AR, false, 10f, 5000f);
    }


    // Called to draw the current frame.
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        if (!mIsActive)
            return;

        // Call our function to render content from SampleAppRenderer class
        mSampleAppRenderer.render();
    }


    // Called when the surface is created or recreated.
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "GLRenderer.onSurfaceCreated");

        // Call Vuforia function to (re)initialize rendering after first use
        // or after OpenGL ES context was lost (e.g. after onPause/onResume):
        vuforiaAppSession.onSurfaceCreated();

        mSampleAppRenderer.onSurfaceCreated();
    }


    // Called when the surface changed size.
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "GLRenderer.onSurfaceChanged");

        // Call Vuforia function to handle render surface size changes:
        vuforiaAppSession.onSurfaceChanged(width, height);

        // RenderingPrimitives to be updated when some rendering change is done
        mSampleAppRenderer.onConfigurationChanged(mIsActive);

        // Init rendering
        initRendering();
    }


    public void setActive(boolean active)
    {
        mIsActive = active;

        if(mIsActive)
            mSampleAppRenderer.configureVideoBackground();
    }


    // Function for initializing the renderer.
    private void initRendering()
    {
       // mCubeObject = new CubeObject();
        mTeapot = new Teapot();

        mRenderer = Renderer.getInstance();

        // Now generate the OpenGL texture objects and add settings
        for (Texture t : mTextures)
        {
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, t.mTextureID, 0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, t.mTextureID[0]);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,
                t.mWidth, t.mHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.mData);
        }
        SampleUtils.checkGLError("ObjectTarget GLInitRendering");

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Vuforia.requiresAlpha() ? 0.0f
            : 1.0f);

        shaderProgramID = SampleUtils.createProgramFromShaderSrc(
            CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER,
            CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "vertexPosition");
        textureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "vertexTexCoord");
        texSampler2DHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "texSampler2D");
        mvpMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
        opacityHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "opacity");
        colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "color");

        // Hide the Loading Dialog
        mActivity.loadingDialogHandler
            .sendEmptyMessage(LoadingDialogHandler.HIDE_LOADING_DIALOG);

    }


    // The render function called from SampleAppRendering by using RenderingPrimitives views.
    // The state is owned by SampleAppRenderer which is controlling it's lifecycle.
    // State should not be cached outside this method.
    public void renderFrame(State state, float[] projectionMatrix)
    {
        // Renders video background replacing Renderer.DrawVideoBackground()
        mSampleAppRenderer.renderVideoBackground();

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // did we find any trackables this frame?
        for (int tIdx = 0; tIdx < state.getNumTrackableResults(); tIdx++)
        {
            TrackableResult result = state.getTrackableResult(tIdx);
            Trackable trackable = result.getTrackable();
            printUserData(trackable);

            if (!result.isOfType(ObjectTargetResult.getClassType()))
                continue;

            ObjectTarget objectTarget = (ObjectTarget) trackable;

                    Matrix44F modelViewMatrix_Vuforia = Tool
                .convertPose2GLMatrix(result.getPose());
            float[] modelViewMatrix = modelViewMatrix_Vuforia.getData();

            // deal with the modelview and projection matrices
            float[] modelViewProjection = new float[16];

            float[] objectSize = objectTarget.getSize().getData();

            Matrix.translateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, objectSize[0]/2, objectSize[1]/2,
                objectSize[2]/2);

            Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, objectSize[0]/2,
                objectSize[1]/2, objectSize[2]/2);

            Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

            // activatrigidBodyTarget.xmle the shader program and bind the vertex/normal/tex coords
            GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false, 0, mTeapot.getVertices());
            GLES20.glUniform1f(opacityHandle, 0.3f);
            GLES20.glUniform3f(colorHandle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTeapot.getTexCoords());

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                mTextures.get(0).mTextureID[0]);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                modelViewProjection, 0);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);


            // pass the model view matrix to the shader
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                modelViewProjection, 0);

            // finally render
            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                    mTeapot.getNumObjectIndex(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                    mTeapot.getIndices());

            // disable the enabled arrays
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            SampleUtils.checkGLError("Render Frame");

        }

        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

        mRenderer.end();
    }


    private void printUserData(Trackable trackable)
    {
        String userData = (String) trackable.getUserData();
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "UserData:Retreived User Data \"" + userData + "\"");
    }


    public void setTextures(Vector<Texture> textures)
    {
        mTextures = textures;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is far, it could be that the Z translation or scaling is wrong. Check if your objectSize[2] is correct. Anyway, you can control the distance with Matrix.translateM  (the last argument is Z)

Comment: what you mean with "Check if your objectSize[2] is correct" , how can i check that is correct?

Comment: See if the size seems reasonable relatively to the x and y sizes, for example.

Comment: objectSize[0]  ::142.5 ; objectSize[1]= 95.0 ; objectSize[2] =95.0
i make it work after excluding translation and scaling than i can see the teapot on my object (even it is a little bit small but works) thank you a lot